# How to scan multiple string from a long string and store it in a char *word[20]?

Tags: c

```
            int res, charRead;
            char *ptr = buff;
            char *searchWord[20];
            int j = 0;
            while(1)
            {
                res = sscanf(ptr, "%s%n", searchWord[j] ,&charRead);
                if(res != 1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                printf("%s\n", searchWord[j]);
                j++;
                ptr = ptr + charRead;

            }
```

The buff array has some strings included. For example, if buff contains "hello world". The result should be that searchWord[0] = "hello", searchWord[1] = "world". I am trying to move each word from that long array to another pointer array. However I am getting seg faults and invalid writes. Thank you for your help.

```
            int j = 0;
            char searchWord[20][20];
            char *ptr;
            ptr = strtok(buff, " ");
            while(ptr != NULL)
            {
                strncpy(searchWord[j][], ptr, 20);
                j++;
                ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
```

This is a changed one, however how do I initialize it so it does not cause any problem.

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `searchWord[j]`.

Comment: You’re not allocating memory for your array. It’s just pointers pointing wherever and dereferencing them is undefined behavior

Comment: Why not use `strtok()`?

Comment: `strtok` is good candidate here.

Comment: Do you think it would be advisable to assign space it in the heap?

Comment: @VINAMRAMUNOT You need to do because you can't be sure about the max number of substrings that can occur and size of each substring.

Comment: `int j = 0;
            char *searchWord[20];
            char *ptr;
            ptr = strtok(buff, " ");
            while(ptr != NULL)
            {
                // printf("%s\n", ptr);
                *searchWord[j] = ptr;
                j++;
                ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }`
@Barmar

Comment: @abhiarora Could you please guide how to allocate that space in the heap using malloc?

Comment: It should just be `searchWord[j] = ptr;`

Comment: `warning: variable ‘searchWord’ set but not used` @Barmar

Comment: It should be used in `printf("%s\n", searchWord[j]);`

Comment: The first several lines of your while loop are not idiomatic.  Just write `while(sscanf(...) == 1) { ...`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @Barmar
would it be possible for you to check out the changed one and suggest imporvements?

Comment: It should be `strncpy(searchWord[j], ptr, 20);`. Didn't you get a warning about wrong type argument from your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @abhiarora Could you please guide how to allocate that space in the heap using malloc?

I have written a small code to illustrate three ways of doing the same thing. The code aren't optimised, efficient and I haven't `freed` the memory that has been allocated dynamically over `heap`. I have skipped some of the required checking in the beginning of these methods. I am assuming that you have better idea of your problem statement and figure out most of the things best suited for your application.

I have tested and compiled the code below on my `Ubuntu 18.04` machine with `gcc` (gcc (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0).

The compilation command was `gcc test.c -o test -Wall -Wextra`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


int method1(const char *buffer, char *arrayOfPtr[50], const int MAX_NUM)
{
    int ndx = 0;

#define MAX_SIZE                    200
    char temp[MAX_SIZE + 1];

    // Method 1
    while (ndx < MAX_NUM) {
        int charRead = 0;
        if (sscanf(buffer, " %s%n", temp, &charRead) != 1)
            break;

        arrayOfPtr[ndx] = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
        if (arrayOfPtr[ndx] == NULL)
            break;

        memcpy(arrayOfPtr[ndx], temp, strlen(temp) + 1);
        buffer += charRead;
        ndx++;
    }

    return ndx;
}

int method2(const char *buffer, char *arrayOfPtr[50], const int MAX_NUM)
{
    char *temp = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    memcpy(temp, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);

    int ndx = 0;
    // Method 2
    while (ndx < MAX_NUM) {
        arrayOfPtr[ndx] = strtok(ndx ? NULL : temp, " ");
        if (arrayOfPtr[ndx] == NULL)
            break;
        ndx++;
    }

    return ndx;
}

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_SUBSTRING             100
#define MAX_SUBSTRING_SIZE                  100

char gBuffer[MAX_NUMBER_OF_SUBSTRING][MAX_SUBSTRING_SIZE];

int method3(const char *buffer, char *arrayOfPtr[50], const int MAX_NUM)
{
    int ndx = 0;
    // Method 3
    while (ndx < MAX_NUM) {

        int charRead = 0;
        if (sscanf(buffer, " %s%n", gBuffer[ndx], &charRead) != 1)
            break;

        arrayOfPtr[ndx] = gBuffer[ndx];
        buffer += charRead;
        ndx++;
    }

    return ndx;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *bfr = "Hello World Stack Overflow";
    char *arrayOfPtr[50];

    int i;
    int size = method1(bfr, arrayOfPtr, sizeof(arrayOfPtr) / sizeof(arrayOfPtr[0]));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("String: %d is \"%s\" of size %lu\r\n", i + 1, arrayOfPtr[i], (unsigned long)strlen(arrayOfPtr[i]));

    return 0;
}
```

Below are the explanations of each method:

1. **Method Number 1:** In this method, I have been allocating memory dynamically using `malloc`. I have been using a `temp` array of characters of size `200` to hold the current c-string. After that, I allocate the memory dynamically of the required size and copy the string from temp using `memcpy`. This method doesn't handle the case when substring of size more than 200 has been feeded to the function.
2. **Method Number 2:** In this method, I have been using `strtok` function declared in `#include <string.h>`. Using well-tested c-standard function reduced the number of lines of code required.
3. **Method Number 3:** In this memory, I have allocated a global buffer for holding strings so that we don't require allocating dynamic memory. **I have skipped some checking in the beginning of this method**. This method has various limitations. It can't work on strings that have substrings of size more than `100` (`MAX_SUBSTRING_SIZE`) and can't handle string that have more than `100` (`MAX_NUMBER_OF_SUBSTRING`) substring in it. Also, if your particular substring has only 5 characters (like `Hello`), then `95` characters memory has been wasted. So, it's not an efficient method.

> However I am getting seg faults and invalid writes.

I would suggest have a look at the `compiler's` warnings. Make sure you have enabled the warning in you `IDE` or using command-line flags.

I have learned tools like `valgrind` and `gdb`. They were very helpful to me while debugging my code for seg faults.